# Prove that every finite subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is conjugate to a finite subgroup of $SU_2$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, linear-groups

I want to prove this proposition.
For any finite subgroup $G$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$, I showed that $G$ is unitary with respect to an inner product that we define properly.
But I couldn't find the conjuction element.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: To find the conjugating element, take the Cholesky decomposition (writing $A=LL^*$) of the inner product matrix $A$ you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a Moore's theorem from 1898 (Eliakim Hastings Moore: 1862-1932). Every finite group $G\leq GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is conjugate to a subgroup of the unitary group $U_n$. In your case $n=2$.

One of the proofs of this theorem explicitly states the conjugate element.
Let
$$
a=\sum_{g\in G}gg^*.
$$
The matrix $a$ is positive-definite, so $a=bb^*$ and
$b^{-1}Gb<U_n$.

For large groups this is not so easy to calculate, but you have $n=2$ and a small group. Try it.

**Addition.**

Let us prove that $b^{-1}xb\in U_n$ for every $x\in G$.

Let $y=b^{-1}xb$. Since $(uv)^*=v^*u^*$ and $a=bb^*$, we have
$$
yy^*=(b^{-1}xb)(b^{-1}xb)^*=b^{-1}xbb^*x^*(b^*)^{-1}=b^{-1}xax^*(b^*)^{-1}.
$$
Now notice that $xax^*=a$. Indeed,
$$
xax^*=x\left(\sum_{g\in G}gg^*\right)x^*=\sum_{g\in G} xgg^*x^*=\sum_{g\in G}(xg)(xg)^*=\sum_{xg\in G}(xg)(xg)^*=a.
$$
Now we can complete the proof
$$
yy^*=b^{-1}xax^*(b^*)^{-1}=b^{-1}a(b^*)^{-1}=b^{-1}bb^*(b^*)^{-1}=e.
$$
Here $e$ is the identity matrix.
We see that $yy^*=e$, hence $y$ is a unitary matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I found the conjugate element in another way. Let call this element U. Now I have to show that UGU^-1 is a subgroup of SU(2). Do you know what is the process? Thanks again.

Comment: @xxyyzz Thank you. It's hard for me to judge your $U$, but perhaps an addendum to my answer would help.

Comment: thanks again. do you know any book, lecture notes etc. for this proof? I have to refer sth like that for I can write this proof in my study.

Comment: Such reasoning I have seen only in the book Yu. I. Merzlyakov, Rational Groups (p. 401). This book has not been translated into English. A more modern proof can be found in the excellent book Michael Artin Algebra (pages 310-312, 1991 edition).